# Correct way of finding Sum of Ratios

Tags: mathematical-statistics, excel

This is more of a statistical question rather than Excel Related. In the attached image, im trying to find out the ratio of Profit/Sales and then calculating overall Profit/Sales

Please let me know which one is correct.[image: Picture1]

Comment: Actually, this is less a statistical question -- since both approaches are *statistically* correct -- than a financial one. Therefore, any decision depends on the environment in which the calculation is being used. Note that once scaled up beyond this simple "toy" data example, the two approaches have hugely differing financial implications and consequences.

Answer (score 1):

In the first method you're equal weighting each time period. In the second method, you're weighting by sales.

Let $p_t$ be profit in period $t$. Let $s_t$ be sales in period $t$. Let $y_t =\frac{p_t}{s_t}$ be profit to sales in period $t$.

#### First method:

Your first method of calculation is to take the sample mean of $y_t$.

$$ \bar{y}^{(1)} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T y_t $$

Since $T=5$, every observation gets weight $\frac{1}{5}$. You're equal weighting each period.

#### Second method:

The second method is:

\begin{align*}
\bar{y}^{(2)} &= \frac{\sum_t p_t}{\sum_t s_t} \\
&= \frac{\sum_t s_t y_t}{\sum_t s_t}\quad \quad \text{since } y_t = \frac{p_t}{s_t}\\
&= \sum_t \left( \frac{s_t}{\sum_t s_t} \right) y_t
\end{align*}

In summary, your second method is equivalent to:

$$\bar{y}^{(2)} = \sum_{t=1}^T w_t y_t\quad \quad w_t = \frac{s_t}{\sum_{t=1}^T s_t}$$

Instead of equally weighting each time period (i.e. $\frac{1}{T}$), you're taking the average of the profit to sales ratio $y_t$ where you **weight each period $t$ by sales**.

#### Which makes more sense?

That's going to depend a lot more on context. If $t$ represents a month and you're thinking about overall, annual profitability, then method 2 is going to be more robust against all kinds of time series issues.

Imagine I'm a ski resort. Basically all my sales occur in Dec, Jan, and Feb. Taking the average where I give December the same weight as September is going to be VERY different than taking the average where I weight Dec 20x as much as September because December has 20x the sales.